# How to raise the trigger if the data for the period are the same?

Tags: zabbix

I have an item, where stored an information of the form "Thu Apr 05 14:22:09 2018". Interval 30 minutes. I need to raise zabbix trigger if this item not change information for the day.

Comment: Isn't there a fuzzytime function for this, together with lastdata()?

Comment: No, it is not what I need :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zabbix cannot compare textual values in a reasonable way. I'd suggest changing the item to store Unix timestamp instead of the human readable string and then using the `delta()` [trigger function](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/appendix/triggers/functions).

Comment: Yes, thanks. Zabbix really does not know how to compare text values, so I had to translate them into a Unix timestamp